# Site Lookup Column As Managed Property

Tags: 2013, search, lookup-column

Please let me know if my logic here is incorrect or suggest better alternative. This is hosted on Office 365.

1. I have a Site Lookup column (EventLookup) that is linked to a list on my Root Site --> Lists/Events
2. I have a subsite with a list that references a (EventLookup) site column --> Lists/MyEvents
3. User creates an item in Lists/MyEvents and selects one of the Events from the Lookup Column
4. I crawl the site and in my crawled properties i can see ows_EventLookUp and ows_EventLookupUp:ID
5. I create a managed property KeyEventID and add ows_EventLookupUp:ID to it.
6. I add a CSWP and set KeyEventID:1 to return any item that has EventLookUp:ID is equal to 1.

Above never works, i cant search bring back any results based on that LookUp column.

Basically my managed property from a site lookup column doesn't work in Content Search Web Part. It is not filterable and doesn't return a value if i use search api to return it either.

help appreciated.

Comment: See this:http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/e25b0090-7177-40b3-b291-611da2c7109a/lookup-field-and-content-search-web-part-in-sp-2013